# How do I get three monitors (HDMI and VGA and laptop internal) to work together in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, external-monitor, vga

I have two display ports on my laptop, Lenovo G580: HDMI and VGA port. If I used one of both to extend my monitor, it works. Also, Both ports works if I turn off built-in display. However, if I turn on all three monitors, only two of three works.

Here is the error message:

```
could not set the configuration for CRTC 65
GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gsd_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code2: could not set the configuration for CRTC 65
```

I checked my CPU, i7-3520M supports up to 3 displays.

What's wrong and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer,](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Lenovo-G580-dual-monitors-support/td-p/1212770?CID=ww:lenovosocial:20x9m6) the dual external monitors are not supported by Lenovo G580, so this is a hardware related problem. It is impossible to have those three displays (one internal and two externals) without any additional docking.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is related, but I lost connection to my third display during the weekend in Ubuntu 18.04. I have a Dell laptop with TB16 Dock. The dock has two display connected to it, but only one of them turns on. Until Friday I had all 3 displays working. I've tried to switch the cable from display port to HDMI and I tried with a spare dock with no success. I think this has something to do with some updates from last week.